# Voltage in a Y-Δ transform

Tags: voltage, resistors, dc, voltage-source

I'm looking for a way to solve the following circuit

[image: Voltage in a delta circuit]

Without the voltage sources on the circuit, I would be using a simple Y-Δ transform. But I'm not sure how I should proceed with them on.

Which methods should I use ?

Comment: Without the voltage sources you didn't need to do anything because there were no voltages and currents.

Comment: This circuit isn't large enough that any of the traditional approaches will work, pick between node-voltage, mesh-current, full Kirchoff's and then solve the simultaneous linear equations.  Or simplify using Thevenin/Norton equivalence and reduce the resulting parallel sources and resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quite simple way to solve this (without Y-Δ-transform). Here is an outline:

Recognize that nodes A and B are connected by 3 parallel Thevenin sources (= voltage source with resistor in series).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6FfVK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Convert each of the Thevenin sources into a Norton source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftVmhQ.png)</sup>

Those 3 Norton sources can be combined very easily into one Norton source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkAEW5.png)</sup>

If you want, you can transform that combined Norton source back into a Thevenin source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWffc9.png)</sup>

Done.